# Bootstrap columns set image col height to text col height

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

i made myself a row with 2 columns with the left one being filled up with text and the right one being an image, now since the image is bigger than the text, i want the image to being scaled down to the size of the text and then use the pull-right class to keep the image aligned right.

here is what i have now:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        // text here
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        // image here
    </div>
</div>
```

for some reason i cant add bootstrap css to a jsfiddle, so i cant show the output, but i can try to explain, the right column where the image is is bigger than the left text column so i want that image to scale with the text column height

i hope that this makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assumed like this way...**<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/8kmakw3w/7/)</kbd>**

Here it will take height size from col-md-8 class and assign it to image...

```
function checkWidth() {
var a=$('.col-md-8').height();
$('img').height(a);
}
checkWidth();
// Bind event listener
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

**HTML Part:**

```
 <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
            <p>Lots here...With tof text he four tiers of grids available you'e bound to run into issues where, at certain breakpoints, your columns don't clear quite right as one is taller than the other. To fix that, use a combination of a .clearfix and o</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <div class="imgAbt">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mazenl77/I-like-buttons-3a/512/Cute-Ball-Go-icon.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
            <p>Lots of text here...Wi8h the four tiers of grids available you're bound to run into issues where, at certain breakpoints, your columns don't clear quite right as one is taller than the other. To fix that, use a combination of a .clearfix and o</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <div class="imgAbt">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mazenl77/I-like-buttons-3a/512/Cute-Ball-Go-icon.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is right. Javascript is the only way, although your fiddle doesn't seem quite right, as the images and text are below and above each other.